# Make isearch skip folded content in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, isearch

**Q:** How can I tell `isearch` to ignore the contents of folded blocks by default in `org-mode` buffers?

More specifically, I'd like `isearch` to ignore contents of [comment blocks](http://orgmode.org/manual/Comment-lines.html) and [drawers](http://orgmode.org/manual/Drawers.html): When authoring documents in `org-mode` I often use comment blocks and custom drawers to store different kinds of notes about the text I am writing. I keep them folded by default to make sure their contents don't distract me:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'org-hide-block-all)
```

This works really well, but won't stop `org-mode` from expanding these blocks if they contain matches for a string I am `isearch`ing.

Answer (score 13):

You can set `search-invisible` to `nil` in your `.emacs` or using Customize. Then, if you *do* want to show matches in invisible text, press `M-s i` while using `isearch`.

(I found this by reading the docs of `isearch-forward` and `isearch-toggle-invisible`, but it is also documented in the manual: see [Special Isearch](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Special-Isearch.html#Special-Isearch).)

This affects *all* buffers, not just Org; if you want to use `nil` in `org-mode` buffers and the default elsewhere you can create a [buffer-local binding](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Intro-to-Buffer_002dLocal.html) in Org buffers:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (make-local-variable 'search-invisible)
            (setq search-invisible nil)))
```

Comment: A buffer-local value would be way more practical than a let binding advice. :-)

Comment: @Malabarba: Very true! (I didn't know that one can use `make-local-variable` to create a buffer-local binding for a variable that is already defined as global -- until now, that is. I'm still learning stuff. :-) ) I'll update the answer.

Comment: Why not use `setq-local` instead of `make-local-variable` and `setq`?

Comment: We could use `setq-local` here of course --and probably should when Emacses before 24.2 don't need to be supported-- because it is [identical to `make-local-variable` with `setq`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Buffer_002dLocal.html#index-setq_002dlocal). The answer was written before wide adoptability of `setq-local`, that's all.

Answer (score 8):

While using `isearch` you can toggle the search on invisible text with `M-s i`.

You can also customize this behaviour with `M-x customize-group isearch` and searching for `Search Invisible`.

Note that this will ignore everything in a folded block, I can't ignore only the text in a commented block.

Comment: The two of us must have been typing at the same time! :-)