# How can I make occur work only on visible text (e.g. org outline)?

Tags: code-folding, overlays, occur, visibility

Is there a way to do an `M-x occur` on only visible text, similar to how you can [make isearch skip folded content](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/77503/730) with `setq-local search-invisible nil`? That way we could occur on for example headings of a folded org tree, or outer keys of a folded json structure, etc.

(I know I can anchor the occur regex to `^\*.*` etc., but it takes enough time that I avoid doing it, and it only helps in that specific case; occur-ing only on what is visible would be nicer.)